# Any idea why std::move is failing here?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

```
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <future>
#include <utility>

void ThFun(std::promise<std::string>&& prms)
{
    std::string hello = "Hello From Future!\n";
    prms.set_value(hello);
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<std::string> prms;
    auto ftr = prms.get_future();
    std::thread th(&ThFun, std::move(prms));
    std::cout << "Hello from Main\n";
    std::string str = ftr.get();
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I get this build error.

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(1140):     error C2664: 'void (std::promise<_Ty> &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::promise<_Ty>' to 'std::promise<_Ty> &&'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(1140) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::_Bind<_Forced,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>::operator ()(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Forced=true,
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Fun=void (__cdecl *const )(std::promise<std::string> &&),
1>              _V0_t=std::promise<std::string>,
1>              _V1_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V2_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V3_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V4_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V5_t=std::_Nil,
1>              <unnamed-symbol>=std::_Nil
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\thread(50) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Bind<_Forced,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Forced=true,
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Fun=void (__cdecl *const )(std::promise<std::string> &&),
1>              _V0_t=std::promise<std::string>,
1>              _V1_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V2_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V3_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V4_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V5_t=std::_Nil,
1>              <unnamed-symbol>=std::_Nil
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\jim\documents\visual studio 11\projects\promisesandfutures    \promisesandfutures\main.cpp(18) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread<void(__cdecl *)(std::promise<_Ty> &&),std::promise<_Ty>>(_Fn,_V0_t &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string,
1>              _Fn=void (__cdecl *)(std::promise<std::string> &&),
1>              _V0_t=std::promise<std::string>
1>          ]
```

I'm using VC11. The error says can't bind an lvalue, but I'm using std::move to make it an rvalue.

Thanks.

**Edit**
std::ref works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the error message it looks like VC11 has made the same mistake that gcc did prior to gcc 4.7: using `std::bind` in the internals of `std::thread`. `std::bind` requires that the arguments are copyable, but `std::thread` does not. This means that move-only types such as `std::promise` cannot be passed as arguments to a thread.

Indeed, your example works with gcc 4.7, or with MSVC 2010 and my [just::thread implementation of the C++11 thread library](http://www.stdthread.co.uk), but fails with a similar error message with gcc 4.6 when using its native library (gcc 4.6 also works when using just::thread).

Comment: I'll post this as a bug at msft. Thanks.